# WPF Putting a table in a tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've tried many different ways to put a table of information into a tooltip using WPF, but it does not seem to work. Does anyone have a simple way of putting a table, or datagrid, of data to work in a tooltip?

Comment: can you share what you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Just override the tooltip template of your control.

The below code shows how to modify a tooltip of button control.

```
<Button.ToolTip>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,5">Open file</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock>
                        Search your computer or local network
                        <LineBreak />
                        for a file and open it for editing.
                        </TextBlock>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Margin="0,8" />
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Image Source="/WpfTutorialSamples;component/Images/help.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                            <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic">Press F1 for more help</TextBlock>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.ToolTip>
```

In this way you can modify the tooltip template of any controls in WPF

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to put a datagrid like you mention in the question you can try something like this

```
<Button> 
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <ToolTip.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test1"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test2"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test3"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test4"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToolTip.Template>
        </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

The above code works perfectly fine. I just checked
[image: Looks like this]

Comment: @NJ : DataGrid is throwing exception for me in my xaml file. It's saying: DataGrid was not found. Please verify you are not missing an assembly reference. The solution by Frebin works for me.

Comment: @code82 The code works fine . you must have made some mistakes